# How do you group 2 calls into 1 condition check in React? (Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Any ideas on how I would do this? I'm having trouble with it since it's all in a  tag so it has a lot of rules i'm not familiar with.
The whole thing draws a graph and this code is played when expandGraph is true -> the user has clicked on the graph to expand it and it draws an underline(first condition) and dotted lines(second condition). I would like to merge them, I'm guessing using fragments

```
   {expandGraph &&
        function StageGrid({ graphHeight }: Props) {
          Array.from(Array(8).keys()).map((y) =>
            Array.from(Array(15).keys()).map((x) => (
              <Line
                key={`${x}${y}`}
                x={x * 7}
                y={y * (graphHeight / 6) + 1}
                strokeWidth={1}
                stroke={'#DBDBDB'}
                points={[0, 0, 3.5, 0]}
              />
            )),
          );
        }}

      {expandGraph &&
        Array.from(Array(15).keys()).map((x) => (
          <div key={x}>
            <Line
              key={x}
              x={x * 7}
              y={graphHeight / 2 + 1}
              strokeWidth={1}
              stroke={'#000000'}
              points={[0, 0, 3.5, 0]}
            />
            <Line
              key={x}
              x={x * 7}
              y={1.3}
              strokeWidth={1}
              stroke={'#000000'}
              points={[0, 0, 3.5, 0]}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, to do that you would use fragments (I also prefer using the shorthand: `<> </>`, but you can use the full `<React.Fragment>` convention if you'd like). Also, I don't see why `StageGrid()` is defined in the JSX since it isn't called anywhere, so I'm a little confused as to whether that is intentional or not, but this example should be exactly what you have, just grouped together.

```
{
  expandGraph && (
    <>
      {
        function StageGrid({ graphHeight }: Props) {
          Array.from(Array(8).keys()).map((y) =>
            Array.from(Array(15).keys()).map((x) => (
              <Line
                key={`${x}${y}`}
                x={x * 7}
                y={y * (graphHeight / 6) + 1}
                strokeWidth={1}
                stroke={'#DBDBDB'}
                points={[0, 0, 3.5, 0]}
              />
            )),
          );
        }
      }

      {
        Array.from(Array(15).keys()).map((x) => (
          <div key={x}>
            <Line
              key={x}
              x={x * 7}
              y={graphHeight / 2 + 1}
              strokeWidth={1}
              stroke={'#000000'}
              points={[0, 0, 3.5, 0]}
            />
            <Line
              key={x}
              x={x * 7}
              y={1.3}
              strokeWidth={1}
              stroke={'#000000'}
              points={[0, 0, 3.5, 0]}
            />
          </div>
        ))
      }
    </>
  )
}
```